# Can someone please explain the output to me?

Tags: c++, c++11

okay, so when i change the " = " in `if( (i = 4) || (i = 5) )` to "`==`" it returns hello world. But when the "`=`" is kept at "=" the output is nothing. It does not give me a syntax error cuz ik you need to put "`==`" inside an if

```
void f( int i )
 {
 if( (i = 4) || (i = 5) ) return;
 cout << "hello world\n" ;
 }

 int main()
 {
 f( 3 );
 f( 4 );
 f( 5 );
 return 0;
 }
```

So when the code is "`if( (i = 4) || (i = 5) )`" output is **nothing** (as in the screen is empty).
when the code is "`if( (i == 4) || (i == 5) )`" output is **hello world**.

my main question is: Why does `==` and `=` make a difference in the output but not give me a syntax error?

Comment: Those are different operators that do different things and have different behavior. Have you looked up the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

As @Carcigenicate said, `==` and `=` is different.

`==` is for comparing and `=` is for assigning.

Comment: oh okay ty. Sorry about the stupid question

Comment: No worries. There is no stupid question. We have our own pain on coding. 

Answer (score 0):

An assignment `a = b` does not only set the value in variable `a` to `b`, but also returns the value of `b`. This way, an assignment like `a = b = c` is possible, because the value returned to be put in `a` is the same as has been set to `b`. You can use this trick in conditionals, as you've done, for example:

```
int x;
while(x = functionWhichCouldReturnZero()){
  // Do something with x
}
```

When C++ tries to interpret the return value as a boolean (`true` or `false`), it interprets `0` as `false`, and all other values as `true`.

On the other hand, with `(a == b)`, this is a pure conditional, and returns `true` if `a` is equal to `b`, otherwise it returns `false`.